# Chrome 31.x support for input:checked+label?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

I have problem with input:checked+label on Chrome 31.x.

Here is code: [demo](http://jsbin.com/egutap/6/edit?html,css,output)

I had in my application buttons like the first in demo and it was working a long time. Yesterday, I sow that one functionality stoped working and I didn't have idea why. Today I'm searching web and find nothing... almost. I found old demo for similar functionality and added to this  inside label. And it stoped working.

Anyone knows what happend or how to fix this problem? I wanted to make changes as little as it is passible. There are two options for me now: JS or remove button and restyle "button".

PS. I know, that button in label isn't semantic, but it isn't my code :P

Comment: `:checked +` has never worked in Chrome as far as I know.

Comment: You are wrong. See demo. "Second" worked from a long, long time. As "First"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No Javascript Solution

**UPDATE: Solving the Click on Label to Get Checked Status Issue**

This also has a pure CSS solution (at least under certain conditions). [See this example](http://jsbin.com/egutap/18/edit) using this css:

```
input + label {position: relative;}
input + label button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

This overlays the `label` over the `button` element, allowing the `label` to acquire the click instead of the `button`. Two consequences of this are:

1. If the actual `button` also needed to register the click, then a js solution like tdroL's answer is the only thing that I believe will work.
2. The click of the `button` does not activate the browser's "pressed button" look, since the `button` is not really being pressed (the `label` is). If one wanted that, then an additional styling change to the button to make a pressed look would need to happen using a selector like `input + label:active button`.

**Solving the Color Issue (which was not the main issue)**

I originally thought the question was about solving the color value of the button, and gave the following answer (which could still be helpful). I think the default value of a `button` element for `color` is not `inherit` as most text is (perhaps this is browser specific). Upon inspection, both Firefox and Chrome for a straight button element show `buttontext` as the value of the `color` property, indicating that the browser is controlling the button color. So a more explicit css is needed to set the `color` of the button, as it is not going to `inherit` the `color` from the `label` element it is nested in (which is what your example is depending upon). [So this css works](http://jsbin.com/egutap/15/edit)):

```
input:checked + label button {color:red}
```

Of course, if you still need the second one working, [css would be this](http://jsbin.com/egutap/16/edit):

```
input:checked + label,
input:checked + label button {
  color:red
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't that I can't change color of text in label. Problem is that I can't check checkbox by clicking label.

Comment: That was really unclear from the question. The css styling `input:checked + label` you mentioned has nothing to do with that browser functionality (rather, it is the linking of the `for` property to the `input`), so I assumed it was the styling/text color that was your issue. I have updated my answer to "fix" the selection issue by pure css as well, which may work okay in some situations and not others (but at least it is addressing now what your real issue was).

Answer (score 2):

It isn't working because Chrome probably adds some kind of "stopPropagation()" for parent labels.

Hacky solution:

```
$(function () {
  $('body').on('click', 'label button', function (e) {

    $(this).closest('label').trigger('click');

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```